# How to get mongodb working on appfog?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, appfog

I'm new to nodeJS, so i was just trying couple of things starting from basics.

I had a problem while retrieving data from MongoDB, So here is the code:

```
var port = (process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var http = require('http');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var mongoUrl = "mongodb://<userid>:<password>@linus.mongohq.com:10090/<db>";
    if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
        mongoUrl = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL;
    }
    selectTable(req, res, mongoUrl);
}).listen(port, host);

var selectTable = function (req, res, mongoUrl) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write("Start\n");
    mongo.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, conn) {
        conn.collection('Test', function (err, coll) {
            coll.find({}, {}, function (err, cursor) {
                cursor.toArray(function (err, items) {
                    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        res.write(JSON.stringify(items[i]) + "\n");
                    }
                    res.end();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

this works fine in my local, it displays the rows, but when i upload it to one of my appfog's app it does not display the rows, it just stops at "Start" and nothing else is displayed.

Please help, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How about checking what comes back in `err`?

Comment: I believe that your MongoDB run on different port(May be in 27017). Have you checked that?

Comment: process.env.VMC_APP_PORT -> am already specifying the port here and also i tried to print the complete URL, it seems just fine.

Comment: Also i've uploaded the same application in nodejitsu, it works fine there, did i miss something?

Comment: I checked again if it's returning any err, and there is none.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the [Document](https://docs.appfog.com/services/mongodb) or the example on [github](https://github.com/appfog/af-node-sample-mongodb/blob/master/server.js).
They provide with **VCAP_SERVICES** for every details you need to connect.
so following (from the doc) will do all the magic.

```
if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES){
var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
var mongo = env['mongodb-1.8'][0]['credentials'];
}
else{
var mongo = {
"hostname":"localhost",
"port":27017,
"username":"",
"password":"",
"name":"",
"db":"db"
}
}
var generate_mongo_url = function(obj){
obj.hostname = (obj.hostname || 'localhost');
obj.port = (obj.port || 27017);
obj.db = (obj.db || 'test');
if(obj.username && obj.password){
return "mongodb://" + obj.username + ":" + obj.password + "@" + obj.hostname + ":" + obj.port + "/" + obj.db;
}
else{
return "mongodb://" + obj.hostname + ":" + obj.port + "/" + obj.db;
}
}
var mongourl = generate_mongo_url(mongo);
```

Comment: It does work when you give the mongo url of the service provided by appfog, but it doesn't work when you try to give any 3rd party url, like mongohq or mongolab